# Workbox -> GlobIgnore doesn't work as intended

Tags: angular, caching, workbox

I have the following workbox-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  globDirectory: "dist/",
  globPatterns: ["**/*.{css,eot,html,ico,jpg,js,json,png,svg,ttf,txt,webmanifest,webm,xml}"],
  globIgnores: [
    '**/*.woff',
    '**/*.woff2',
    '**/assets/fonts/**/*',
    '**/assets/scripts/**/*'
  ],
  dontCacheBustURLsMatching: new RegExp(".+.[a-f0-9]{20}..+"),
  maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4Mb
  swSrc: "src/assets/scripts/c2oWorkerSrc.js",
  swDest: "dist/c2oWorker.js",
};
```

but it always precaches the .woff and .woff2 files, no matter, what I write in globIgnore. What do I do wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect based on your configuration. Is there a copy of your project on GitHub somewhere, or some other way that I can try running your build myself?